# Merge/Combine two adjacent contour lines with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, error-000735

I am a Python beginner; I found a script in [Append or merge consecutive line segments (contours) as one single line of the same elevation value](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63175/append-or-merge-consecutive-line-segments-contours-as-one-single-line-of-the-s)

I am trying to use it to merge 2 shapefiles (1 ft -contours):
N1_Terrain_SurfaceContour ( 0 -12) ft elevetions and 
N1_Terrain_SurfaceContour (0-11)

These are located at my workspace: 
C:\Users\efa8\Documents\AA_NRMD_Bvrd\CONTOUR PJ\Contour.mdb

Each one has the same fields: OBJECTID, Shape*, Contour and Shape_Lenght. I used "Contour" instead "ELEV_FT" in the script (as you suggested).

I got the following ERROR (Parameters are not valid):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\efa8\Documents\AA_NRMD_Bvrd\CONTOUR PJ\Contourlines merge BREVARD.py", line 35, in <module>
    arcpy.Merge_management(contourList, "contour_merge.shp")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3788, in Merge
    raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000735: Input Datasets: Value is required
Failed to execute (Merge).
```

---

This is the script that I adapted:

Contour_Merge_And_Dissolve.py - CONTOUR PJ BREVARD COUNTY

```
# Import modules
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\efa8\Documents\AA_NRMD_Bvrd\CONTOUR PJ\Contour.mdb"
from arcpy import env

# Define functions
def min_max(featureClass, fieldName):
    listItems = []
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureClass)
    for row in rows:
        listItems.append(row.getValue(fieldName))
    del rows
    listItems.sort()
    listMin = listItems[0]
    listMax = listItems[-1]
    return listMin, listMax

# Arguments
contourList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #input shapefiles, ElevationContours
outFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #output folder

# set workspace and overwrite option
arcpy.env.workspace = outFolder
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"
arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Disabled"

# local variables
dissolveFields = ["Contour"] # change field name here

# Process: Merge
arcpy.AddMessage("Merging contours...")
arcpy.Merge_management(contourList, "contour_merge.shp")

# Get Min/Max values of Contour field
ft_min, ft_max = min_max("contour_merge.shp", "Contour") # change field name here
ft_range = ft_max - ft_min

arcpy.AddMessage("Contour MIN: " + str(ft_min))
arcpy.AddMessage("Contour MAX: " + str(ft_max))

# Set progressor
arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "Breaking apart contours...", 0, ft_range, 1)
arcpy.AddMessage("Breaking apart contours...")

# Break apart and dissolve for each Contour value
mergeList = []
counter = ft_min
while counter <= ft_max:
    arcpy.SetProgressorLabel("Breaking out " + str(counter) + "ft contours...")
    arcpy.AddMessage("Attempting " + str(counter) + "ft contours...")
    counter_str = str(counter)
    counter_str = counter_str.replace("-", "neg")
    thisLyr = "elev_" + counter_str + "_lyr"
    thisDis = "elev_" + counter_str + "_dissolve.shp"
    where_clause = '"Contour" = ' + str(counter) # change field name here
    # Make Layer
    arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer("contour_merge.shp", thisLyr)
    # Select by attributes
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(thisLyr, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
    # Dissolve Layer to new shape
    arcpy.Dissolve_management(thisLyr, thisDis, dissolveFields, "", "SINGLE_PART", "DISSOLVE_LINES")
    # Add to mergeList
    mergeList.append(thisDis)
    counter += 1
    arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()

arcpy.ResetProgressor()

# Merge contours
arcpy.AddMessage("Merging dissolved layers...")
arcpy.Merge_management(mergeList, "contour_dissolve.shp")

# Multipart to singlepart
arcpy.AddMessage("Converting multipart to singlepart...")
arcpy.MultipartToSinglepart_management("contour_dissolve.shp", "contour_singlepart.shp")

# Clean up
for shape in mergeList:
    arcpy.Delete_management(shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

First order of business: you are passing "contour_merge.shp" as one of the parameters.  You should store the full path to this shapefile in the beginning like this:

```
contour_merge = r"full/path/to/shapefile/contour_merge.shp"
```

and then replace `"contour_merge.shp"` with `contour_merge`.  What you currently have, because of how you have set the workspace, makes the script interpret the string `"contour_merge.shp"` as `"C:\Users\efa8\Documents\AA_NRMD_Bvrd\CONTOUR PJ\Contour.mdb\contour_merge.shp"` which is not a valid file path.

Also, when you set your workspace, or reference any file path, always use the r"path\to\stuff" format.  The 'r' tells python to interpret the '\' as a backslash, not as an escape character.

There may be other errors, but this should solve the one you posted about in this question.